# Content Visibility for Wordpress is not working (Drafts, public etc.)

Tags: loop, draft

I have an old WordPress installation. Unfortunately, public posts and drafts are displayed on the front. I think it's because of the wordpress loop. The following code is used:

```
<section class="container container-fluid">

    <div id="layout" style="padding: 0 -15px;">
    <?php
    if (has_tag('Karriere')) 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $args                   = array('offset'        => 0,
                                    'numberposts'   => 12,
                                    'limit'         => 12,
                                    'post_type'     => "post",
                                    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC',
                                    'category'      => '26,60',
                                    'tag'           => 'Karriere');
    //$args                 = array('numberposts' => 2);                                

    $recent_posts           = wp_get_recent_posts($args, ARRAY_A);
    $_SESSION['home_offset']    = count($recent_posts);

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        $post_uri           = get_permalink($recent['ID']);
        //$post_image           = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent['ID']) );
        $post_image         = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent['ID']), 'vorschaubild');
        $post_image         = $post_image[0];

        $post_categoryList  = array();
        $post_categories    = get_the_category($recent['ID']);

        foreach($post_categories as $post_category){
            $post_categoryList[]    = $post_category->slug;
        }

        $content            = explode("<!--more-->", $recent['post_content']);
        $content            = $content[0];
        $content            = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $content);
        $content            = preg_replace('/<div id=\"(.*?)\" class=\"(.*?)\">>(.*?)<\/div>/', "", $content);


    ?>
    <div>
        <div class="wrapper-karriere-box" style="padding: 0 5px;">
            <? //item echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>
            <a href="<?=$post_uri?>" title="<?=$recent["post_title"]?>">
                <div class="newsBox" data-categories="<?=implode(",", $post_categoryList)?>">
                    <?php
                    if($post_image !== false && $post_image !== NULL){
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?=$post_image?>" style="width: 100%;" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="news-box-headline">
                    <h3><?=$recent["post_title"]?></h3>
                    <p><?=$content?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

what i have to change that public posts and drafts are not shown in frontend (for unregistered users).

I hope somebody can help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see only the "publish" post, you have to specified the "post_status".

The documentation of the [wp_get_recent_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/) function said, that if no "post_status" is specified the function used the default values "draft, publish, future, pending, private".

```
$defaults = array(
    'numberposts'      => 10,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);
```

To distinguish between logged in and unlogged users, you could use the function [is_user_logged_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946972/wordpress-check-if-user-is-logged-in)